# How to identify different scopes

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope, anonymous-function

I'm using [this library](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/) to add a custom context menu to my jQuery plugin. But at some point I have a strange issue which I think is related to the way scopes interact. Basically I have two objects, which are the same but built in two very little different ways, one of it works as expected, the other one doesn't.

I'll add some piece of my code, unfortunately it's big and complex enough to make a jsFiddle of it, I'll try to make one if necessary.

```
$.contextMenu({
  selector : [jQUery selector],
  build : function() {
    // some things to do here...

    var contextMenuItems = {}; // list of all the menu entries
    var actions = [{ label : "1" }, { label : "2" }];

    $.each(actions, function(key, value) {
      var newSubMenu = {}; // sub menu
      // some other things...

      // FIRST OBJECT, DOESN'T WORK
      var subMenu = {
        sep1 : "-",
        remove : {
          callback : function() {
            console.log(action);
          }
        }
      }

      // SECOND OBJECT, WORKS AS EXPECTED
      var subMenu2 = {
        sep1: "-",
      };

      subMenu2["remove"] = {
        callback : function() {
            console.log(action);
          }
      };

      $.extend(contextMenuItems[value.label], { items : $.extend(newSubMenu, subMenu) }); (1)
      $.extend(contextMenuItems[value.label], { items : $.extend(newSubMenu, subMenu2) }); (2)
    });
  }
});
```

Basically, I add the same submenu for each entry of the context menu. When I click the submenu entry `"remove"`, I want it to log the parent label. But if I add the `'subMenu'` objects (line (1)), it always logs the first 'action', if I add the 'subMenu2' object (line (2)), the correct label is displayed. Can someone explain me why is that?